# Strange redirect after Magento transfer from an old website to new website

Tags: base-url, 301-redirect

I have moved my database and Magento files to my new domain as had problem with my old domain. I have changed the `local.xml` file to point to the new database and I've changed `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` in the database and I searched for any other section in the database that had my old domain name.

My problem is that if you put my domain name www.example.co.uk gets redirected to www.example.com, I have spoken to my host company and they say the domain is setup correctly and it's a problem with the Magento files. If I remove all Magento files it doesn't redirected to the old domain.

If anyone can advice what other file I need to look at to stop the redirection I will be very grateful.

I look forward in hearing back from you.

Comment: Did you check your .htaccess file ? Index.php ? Try looking for your old domain name in the file: run 'grep -r "yourolddomain" .' in a console

Answer (score 2):

```
1) Copy all file of site to new host
2) Database setting
    i. App/etc/local.xml
    -- Change setting here of new database in new server
```

3) Url Configuration:

```
Open phpmyadmin 
find core_config_data table 
find web/unsecure/base_url and change to new URL 
find web/secure/base_url and change to new URL 

4) Clear cache
5) Remove the php.ini file if there is any before placing original files

# Change media directory permission to 777
```

> Follow this solution. if didnt work then i can help your personally on phone and email as you need it on urgent basis.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's a cache issue.
Try to clean up cache directories (cache, full_page_cache) and sessions (just to avoid some errors).

And you know, I prefer replace an old domain with new one in the SQL dump file.
You may use this command

```
$ sed -r 's/(www\.)?source\.domain\.com/target-server.domain.com/g' inputfile.sql > outputfile.sql
```